# How to get scrolling event in query?

Tags: jquery

I want to fire one or do some task while i start scrolling  of div contend .I check touchend, touchstart event it sometime fire ,some time not.Is there any other way to get this event of scrolling?

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/s66Ww/3/

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '#realTimeContents', function() {
                         alert("--")
                         isScrolling=false;
                         $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", "")
                     //    $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", null)

});
$(document).on('click', '#realTimeContents', function() {
                         alert("-Click-")

                         $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", "")
                       //  $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", null)

});

$(document).on('touchend', '#realTimeContents', function() {
                         alert("-end-")
                         isScrolling=false;
                         $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", "")
                      //   $('div#realTimeContents').css("height", null)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('touchstart click touchend', '#realTimeContents', function(e) {
    alert(e.type);
    $(this).css("height", "")
});
```

Comment: checking tell you in 15 min

Answer (score 0):

try following, what about we bind div scrolling event and get what we desire:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){ 
  if(isScrolling()){ 
     alert("scrolling");
 } 
}); 

function isScrolling() {   
  var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop(); 
  return (scrollPosition > 100); 
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s66Ww/5/

i hope it helps.

Comment: can you use like a document ?

Comment: $(document). scroll ?

Comment: what do you mean? capture it on whole body instead of div?

Comment: Because i need to add on another js file ? can you change fiddle?

Comment: can you change your fiddle using document.on is scrolling like function ?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34821/discussion-between-user2563256-and-maverickosama92)